# Why does a urllib2 post request to a GoogleApp Engine app behind https become an empty get request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, post, get, urllib2

I'm coming across a rather strange problem in a small app I've made for Google App Engine.  This is not intended to be accessed by a browser but to provide a kind of rudimentary REST API for another system.  This is the basic structure of the app:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        <do good stuff>
    def get(self):
        raise Exception("Cannot call this app through a get request")

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/objviewer/', MainPage)],debug=True)
```

It works fine with this in my app.yaml:

```
- url: /objviewer/
  script: gaeobjviewer.app
```

and with this code from a python script to call it:

```
encodedurl = urllib.urlencode({'tablename':tablename,'objid':objid})
# uploadservers[uploadkey] in the next line is a URL
response = urllib2.urlopen(uploadservers[uploadkey], data = encodedurl)
print response.read()
```

Now, in my app.yaml, suppose I add in a "secure: always" line:

```
- url: /objviewer/
  secure: always
  script: gaeobjviewer.app
```

The script promptly fails and claims it's being called with a get request.  self.request.GET reports an empty dictionary.

Changing the protocol from http to https or vice versa in the urllib2.urlopen call makes no difference.

In the available literature on https I can find nothing about an empty GET request.  Nor is there any reference to this in the GAE documentation that I can find.  Why might this be occurring?

Comment: What is the url in `uploadservers[uploadkey]`? In particular, does it end in a '/'?

Comment: @ShankarG In the past I have run into this when App Engine does a redirect to the final URL. HTTP cannot redirect to a POST so the final request becomes a GET. What is the value in uploadservers[uploadkey] when doing the HTTPS request?

Comment: Yes it ends in a slash- https://<appname>.google.com/objviewer/. Is that the cause of tge problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that setting the calling URL to https, and then removing the final slash (if you have one), will result in a post request being sent.  I don't know why this is the case, but clearly it has something to do with redirects, as noted in Bryce Cutt's comment.